# CAN bus polarity?

Tags: can

When connecting a CAN bus, does the polarity of the two lines matter, or is it simply the differential that the circuit decodes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it matters,
CAN_H of either device has to connect with CAN_H of each other and same for CAN_L as well as shown below.

[image]

Comment: It might be worth adding that the effect of not doing that is that every data bit that is sent gets inverted.

Comment: Actually, bits aren't inverted with can, the bus won't work at all. With CAN state 1 is "recessive" and differential voltage is close to zero. State 0 is "dominant" and there CAN_L goes low and CAN_H goes high.

Comment: Oh, this was an old question that popped up to front page... Well I'll still leave my comment there :)